# Запись в БД одной кнопкой

Tags: php

Есть цикл где выводятся записи из БД.В цикле есть форма с кнопкой "ОК"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на неё идёт запись в БД. (Отнимает **60** от общего количества очков у пользователя с ником указанным в левой части блока)
Можно ли реализовать это как то с одной кнопкой. Что бы допустим в самом низу или в начале была одна кнопка "ОК" при нажатии на которую все записи записались куда надо. (Отнялось у каждого пользователя своё количество очков)

Comment: Картинка тут не поможет, покажите ваш код, вы что то пробовали делать?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос - Можно.

Comment: Может подскажите, как? @u_mulder

Comment: Собрать все идшники записей в этой таблице, передать на их сервер, на сервере сделать столько запросов, сколько идшников пришло.

Comment: `UPDATE users SET score = score - 60 WHERE username IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')`